# React-select: how to close panel?

Tags: reactjs, hide, panel, react-select

I have a react-select instance with a custom option component. When I select an option, the panel doesn't close. I have to click outside the select to make it happen. Is there any kind of global prop I can use? For exemple in Reakit there is popover.hide(). I don't see anything like this in React-select when console logging the props.

Here is my code:

```js
const CustomOption = ({children, onSelect, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
          <Chip
            label="SELECT ME"
            onClick={() => onSelect(props.data)}
          />
    </div>
  );
};

const MySelect = ({onSelect) => {
  const customOption = {
    Option: ({ children, ...props }) => <CustomOption {...{children, onSelect, ...props}} />};

  return (
        <Select
          isClearable={true}
          options={availableChoices}
          components={customComponents}
        />
  );
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: when you use custom components in React-Select, you need to pass the ref as well. So:

```js
const CustomOption = ({children, onSelect, innerRef, innerProps, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <div ref={innerRef} {...innerProps}>
      {children}
          <Chip
            label="SELECT ME"
            onClick={() => onSelect(props.data)}
          />
    </div>
  );
};

const MySelect = ({onSelect) => {
  const customOption = {
    Option: ({ children, innerRef, innerProps,...props }) => <CustomOption {...{children, onSelect, innerRef, innerProps, ...props}} />};

  return (
        <Select
          isClearable={true}
          options={availableChoices}
          components={customComponents}
        />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleInputChange = input => {
    this.setState({ open: !!input });
}

<Select
    onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
    menuIsOpen={this.state.open}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, I've seen this answer on another thread. It doesn't work. Or maybe I'm implementing it wrong. Would you have a sandbox with a working exemple?

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.